# I can SSH and RDP to an Azure VM but the browser times out

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, connection-timeout

I have deployed a Network License Manager for MATLAB 2022b Azure Virtual Machine (VM) from the Azure Marketplace. The deployment spins up a Windows Server 2019 VM of Standard_B1s class and it seems to be successful because I can ssh, from WSL, and RDP to the VM. However, if I try to access the license manager portal through a browser from home or office, with either Firefox or MS Edge I get the much dreaded "The connection has timed out" and "Hmmm… can't reach this page xxx.yyy.zzz.www took too long to respond" respectively.

I have the following inbound and settings rules in my Network Security Group (NSG). All the rules have been set up by the VM and I have only changed the priorities of allow-https and allow-ssh to 100 and 110 respectively and the fake Source address that I input at the VM configuration page to 0.0.0.0/0 I have restarted the VM after to propagate the changes.
[Inbound and outbound rules of the VM NSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPutq.png)

This aerospace engineer is totally stuck because the (MATLAB) license manager only starts if a license file is loaded through the portal and the portal can only be accessed through the browser. I have also tried to start the license manager at the command line but failed.

Comment: @VenkatV the VM Computer name is netlm-server assigned at VM creation by the folks who wrote the VM.

Comment: I am trying to access the vm from a browser on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access your vm in browser, Check the network firewall rule of service and inside of the vm check the port 22 is actually operational.

***"The connection has timed out"*** error usually occurs if you have installed firewall or security software on your computer it may be preventing access to the virtual machine.

In your task bar type windows defender firewall -> change notification setting

[image]

Turn off window defender firewall like below:

[image]

Disable the firewall and try to activate port 22 by using below commands like below:

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw status
ufw allow 22/tcp
```

[image]

- Try to check license server details to make sure that you are using the correct hostname and port number.
- Check whether the client machine is authorized to use the licenses on the license server.
- If still the issue persists, try to restart the license and client machine and try.

Now try to access Network license manager via browser and check

***Reference***:

[Run Network License Manager from Microsoft Azure  - MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/cloudcenter/ug/run-network-license-manager-from-azure-marketplace.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried the the windows firewall setting but was not able to access the license manager portal VM. I deleted the VM and this morning spun up another one that works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the original VM and all its accoutrements and started a new one that works.